# How to mask UI with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, masking

I have a little JavaFX-application which does some calculations. While it´s processing I want to mask/grey out the UI and show a non-clickable dialog with some info-text. I couldn´t find any method which would help me ...

I would really appreciate some help! ;)

Many thanks and best regards
Wiesi

Comment: For the first, you can call `setDisable(true)` on the root of the scene. For the dialog, consider an [`Alert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) with `AlertType.NONE`. Post specific questions with code if you can't make these work.

Comment: I´d really thought I tried this before ... anyway ... it´s working! Thanks a lot James_D!